# C# Entity Framework Moq exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have `IDataService` that contains generic crud operations

```
public interface IDataService<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(string[] includes = null);
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
    Task<T> Create(T entity);
    Task<T> Update(int id, T entity);
    Task<bool> Delete(int id); 
}
```

and I have class `GenericDataService<T>` that implements the `IDataService` interface:

```
public class GenericDataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : DomainObject 
{
    private readonly DeployToolDBContexFactory _contexFactory;

    public GenericDataService(DeployToolDBContexFactory contexFactory)
    {
        _contexFactory = contexFactory;
    }

    public async Task<T> Create(T entity)
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            EntityEntry<T> createdResult = await contex.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await contex.SaveChangesAsync();
            return createdResult.Entity;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            T entity = await contex.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);
            contex.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            await contex.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<T> entities = await contex.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
            return entities;
        }
    }
   
    public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            T entity = await contex.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);
            return entity;
        }
    }
   
    public async Task<T> Update(int id, T entity)
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            entity.Id = id;
            contex.Set<T>().Update(entity);
            await contex.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(string[] includes = null)
    {
        using (DeployToolDBContex contex = _contexFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var query = contex.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

            foreach (var include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

To create objects I'm using a data store class that executes operations with the `DataService` object:

```
public class DataStore
{
    private static DataStore instance = null;

    public static DataStore Instance
    {
        get
        {
            instance = instance == null ? new DataStore() : instance;
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public IDataService<User> userDataService;

    public DataStore()
    {
        this.userDataService = new GenericDataService<User>(new DeployToolDBContexFactory());  
    }
}
```

For example, user creation :

```
private async void AddUser()
{
    User user = new User()
                    {
                        UserName = UserNameTxt,
                        RoleId = RoleSelected.Id
                    };
    await DataStore.Instance.userDataService.Create(user);
}
```

I'm new to Moq and I want to write unit tests, for example, test of user creation

```
[Test]
public async Task CreateUser()
{
    Mock<DeployToolDBContexFactory> dbContextFactory = new Mock<DeployToolDBContexFactory>();
    Mock<DeployToolDBContex> dbContextMock = new Mock<DeployToolDBContex>(dbContextFactory.Object);

    var user = new User()
                   {
                       UserName = "testName"
                   };
    var mock = new Mock<GenericDataService<User>>(new DeployToolDBContexFactory());
    mock.Setup(m => m.Create(user)).ReturnsAsync(new User() { UserName = user.UserName}).Verifiable();
        var service = new GenericDataService<User>(dbContextFactory.Object);
        User u = await service.Create(user);
        Assert.AreEqual(u.UserName , user.UserName);
}
```

I'm getting this error :

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: m => m.Create(user)
> Non-overridable members (here: GenericDataService.Create) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I tried to set DbSet as virtual.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why you creating new `GenericDataService`, called `service` and use it instead of `mock` for creating user in test?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are a bit mixed up with mocking and what exactly you should be testing. Your GenericDataService is essentially a Generic Repository pattern. This is actually an anti-pattern for EF, but there is plenty to read up on why you shouldn't use it with EF... Repository patterns in general *are* a good thing for facilitating unit testing, however this is because they serve as a boundary to ***avoid*** needing to try and mock a `DbContext` and its `DbSets`.

Firstly, your Test is testing the wrong thing. The test should be testing whatever method that will be calling your AddUser method. Whether this is in a Controller or a Service, etc. That controller would have a dependency of `IDataService<User>` declared which we would be mocking in order to test the controller:

For the sake of argument I've made AddUser() a public method. In your case you should have a public action or method that calls AddUser and would set up a test for that method. You should also structure your code to avoid being dependent on module-level state. For instance an AddUser method should not be reliant on private/protected state, it should ultimately be getting parameters to do things like perform actions or modify state. (kept to a minimum)

So let's assume we want to test a method that should call the DataService Create method and Create is expected to have added the item to the DBContext and assigned an ID. The purpose of the unit test is not to assert what EF actually does, but rather what the code under test should do with the results:

```
[Test]
public void EnsureAddUserCreatesUser()
{
    const string userName = "New User";
    const int roleId = 4;
    const int UserId = 101;
    var mockUserDataService = new Mock<IDataService<User>>();
    mockUserDataService.Setup(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<User>())).Callback(m => {m.UserId = userId;});

    var testController = new UserController(mockUserDataService.Object);
    var user = await testController.AddUser(userName, roleId);
    Assert.IsNotNull(user);
    Assert.AreEqual(userId, user.UserId);
    Assert.AreEqual(userName, user.UserName);
    Assert.AreEqual(roleId, user.RoleId);
    mockUserDataService.Verify(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once);        
}
```

What a test like this does is set up a mock of our repository/data service telling it to expect its input parameter. Since our AddUser method will be creating a new user based on some values, we tell it to expect `It.IsAny<User>()` which says "expect a user". From there we can have the mock perform some basic actions as if the DbContext added our user successfully such as populating a PK. This example populates the PK using the `Callback` method which accepts whatever User was passed in then sets our known PK. The value itself does not matter since we aren't actually inserting data, we just want a known value to get back that we can assert that the mock was actually called. Normally the AddUser might also expect to check the resulting data and return something like a success state with an ID. In this example I had the AddUser return the User.  Other tests you might want to assert the behaviour if the AddUser attempts to add a duplicate user. In these cases the Moq might Throw an exception or otherwise return a different result.

From there we have returned the User, so we just assert the values are what were expected, including the PK, and that our mocked method  was actually called.

Ultimately when it comes to unit testing, the key points are:

- Your DataService/Repository serves as the boundary for the tests. (What you mock)
- Your tests test business logic above this boundary.
- Your tests mock the boundary, capturing all expected calls to that boundary, and either return known state, take action on passed in state, or throw exceptions based on what behaviour you want to test.
- Your tests can then assert the mocks to verify that methods that were expected to be called were called, and any methods that were *not* expected to be called were not called. (`Times.None`)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.
I have seen a number of examples where each entity has an interface and service.
For example, Account entity there will be an interface that will be inherited from the IDataService <Account> interface
And an AccountDataService class that implements the interface.
The thing is, my app contains a lot of entities. Should I make the transition to an architecture where each entity has its own interface and service?

Comment: another thing , i dont have any controller. AddUser method is in the UserViewModel. that is the reason i tried to Mock the GenericDataService. I dont have any class that takes IDataService as parameter.

Comment: What type of application is this? WPF? Web Application?  I'm guessing WPF /w MVVM in which case the unit test would be against your ViewModel's top-level methods/events. Where events can be a bit messy to test an alternative is to use `internal` pass-through methods that accept arguments provided by the event handler (which might resort to private state) Your unit test project can be permitted visibility of internal methods by adding [InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssemblyName")] in your assembly's app info.

Comment: I don’t pass the IDataService as parameter via constructor or function, I create it inside the function.  How I will pass the mock.object ? Is there another way or should I add parameter to functions?

Comment: To employ unit testing and mocking you need to adopt inversion of control / dependency injection. If code is dependent on something, that dependency should be provided to it so that the dependency can be substituted with a mock. To be test-able, code cannot `new` up dependencies.